# It is possible to manipulate a list generated with findall?

Tags: list, prolog

The context is the following in my program: I have some `students`, of a certain `country` and with certain `years` of study, as follows in this prolog code:

```
student('Steve Morris').
student('Joe Jez').
student('Carlos Sethi').
student('Natasha Carter').

country('Steve Morris', usa).
country('Joe Jez', usa).
country('Carlos Sethi', usa).
country('Natasha Carter', france).

years('Steve Morris', 3).
years('Joe Jez', 1). 
years('Carlos Sethi', 4).
years('Natasha Carter', 4). 

scholarship(A) :- country(A,B), B = france.
scholarship(A) :- years(A,C), C > 2.
```

I want to give one and just one scholarship to one of my students. To do this, I will use **some rules that will raise the "scholarship factor"**, and **the student who gets the greater scholarship factor will get the scholarship**.

The first rule states that the student must come from France, and the second rule states that the student must have more than two years of study.

So, when I execute `scholarship(X)`, this is what I get:

```
?- scholarship(X).
X = 'Natasha Carter' ;    % Only student who matches the first rule
X = 'Steve Morris' ;      % All students from now on, match the second rule
X = 'Carlos Sethi' ;
X = 'Natasha Carter'.
```

With that said, **I'm trying to do a program that tries to get the name of the student who finally gets the scholarship**. To start, I've tried first to execute a predicate `findall` to filter all the student that match these rules one by one, and put it on a list:

```
?- findall(X, scholarship(X), L).
L = ['Natasha Carter', 'Steve Morris', 'Carlos Sethi', 'Natasha Carter'].
```

Which is an expected result, because of the use of `scholarship(X)`.

Now, looks like I will need the generated list to filter the results and satisfy what I'm looking for. Take in mind that in the example above, the result that I'm expecting to reach, at least, is a list which indicates the student and his scholarship factor, something like this (not necessarily exact):

```
[['Natasha Carter', 2], ['Steve Morris', 1], ['Carlos Sethi', 1]].
```

It is a way to manipulate the list generated with findall? Or I certainly need another way to solve this?

**Edit:** There's something important about the problem modeling: **All rules have the same scholarship factor value**, so when a student satisfy a rule, no matter which one, the scholarship factor should rise up to 1.

**Updates to the problem**: Thanks to Mog I have an approach of the problem, applying `msort/2` using a secondary list, this is what I've got:

```
?- findall(X, scholarship(X), L), msort(L, L1).
L = ['Natasha Carter', 'Steve Morris', 'Carlos Sethi', 'Natasha Carter'],
L1 = ['Carlos Sethi', 'Natasha Carter', 'Natasha Carter', 'Steve Morris'].
```

Comment: You can start by sorting your list, thanks to `msort/2`. Once it's done a simple predicate can be written that increments a counter after each consecutive similar element and returns the desired result.

Comment: Minor: Replace `country(A,B), B = france.` par `country(A, france).`

Comment: Sort of an approach to the problem, I executed the following command `?- findall(X, scholarship(X), L), msort(L, L1).` and this was the output:
`L = ['Natasha Carter', 'Steve Morris', 'Carlos Sethi', 'Natasha Carter'],
L1 = ['Carlos Sethi', 'Natasha Carter', 'Natasha Carter', 'Steve Morris'].`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found myself an alternate solution by the use of a registry structure called:

```
reg(C, N)
```

where `C` is the name of the person, and `N` is the number of times the name of the person appears on the list generated with `findall` (The use of `msort/2`, for effects of this solution, it's just for order purposes).

```
listsort(L1) :- findall(X, scholarship(X), L), msort(L, L1).

compress([],[]).
compress([X|Xs],Ys):-comp(Xs,X,1,Ys).

comp([],C,N,[reg(C,N)]).
comp([X|Xs],X,N,Ys):-N1 is N+1, comp(Xs,X,N1,Ys).
comp([X|Xs],Y,N,[reg(Y,N)|Ys]):-  X\=Y, comp(Xs,X,1,Ys).

predic(S2) :- listsort(S1), compress(S1, S2).
```

So the output for the original problem looks similar to the proposed one (the only difference is that in the original one the registries are ordered by `N`:

```
?- predic(K).
K = [reg('Carlos Sethi', 1), reg('Natasha Carter', 2), reg('Steve Morris', 1)]
```

Answer (score 1):

the simpler way should be to augment `scholarship(X)` with a rank (I've added the rule 'index'), then use setof to get a sorted list, from lower to higher ranking:

```
scholarship(1,A) :- country(A,B), B = france.
scholarship(2,A) :- years(A,C), C > 2.

?- setof(R-X, scholarship(R,X), L).
```

note I changed the list' elements to a more useful format, exploiting the sorting that setof perform.

*edit*: sorry, I suggested an useless modification. A more appropriate answer would suggest

```
?- findall(N-X, (bagof(_, scholarship(X), T), length(T, N)), L).
L = [1-'Carlos Sethi', 2-'Natasha Carter', 1-'Steve Morris'].
```

Comment: Your code works, but there's the problem that the students are ranked according to the number of the rule, when I am looking to order the students according to the scholarship factor obtained by the evaluation of the rules.

Comment: @CristianC In general (and this goes for all programming, not just Prolog) by making the rest of your requirements explicit, you will enable the rest of the system to make decisions as a result. CapelliC may not have read your mind correctly, but the technique will generalize to whatever your actual problem is, and in a simpler manner than trying to manipulate the inner workings of Prolog builtins.

Comment: Thanks Daniel. I was effectively a bit tired tonight, and didn't understand the question.